# In plain TeX, How to make a part of text in two(or multi) columns?

Tags: plain-tex

To put it simple, I would like to make a little part of my document appears to be in two columns.

However, As most of that should be in a single column, I have a little doubt that whether tangling with `\pagecontent` or `\output` since it's only for, say, less than 1 page or even a few paragraphs. (If that's the best way I would be glad to take that though)

So, could anyone kindly give me some insights of putting part with two columns within a normal document in plain TeX?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

Some time ago I have written an output routine for Plan TeX with multicolumn support and the right float order. Tell me if you are interested. :)

Edit: Here is my solution as promised.

```
\catcode`\@=11
% \protected\def\glet{\global\let} % if you do not use LuaTeX
\def\raggedbottom{\global\r@ggedbottomtrue} % if you are interested in grid typesetting

\newdimen\fullhsize
\newdimen\fullvsize
\fullhsize 20.5cm% change as you like
\fullvsize 26\baselineskip
\advance\fullvsize by \topskip
%
\hsize\fullhsize
\vsize\fullvsize

% Help macros:
\def\@gobble#1{}

\newdimen\@savsk
\newcount\@savsf
\def\@bsphack{% from LaTeX
    \relax
    \ifhmode
    \@savsk\lastskip
    \@savsf\spacefactor
    \fi}
\def\@esphack{%
    \relax
    \ifhmode
    \spacefactor\@savsf
    \ifdim\@savsk>\z@
    \ifdim\lastskip=\z@
    \nobreak \hskip\z@skip
    \fi
    \ignorespaces
    \fi
    \fi}


\maxdeadcycles100

\newdimen\@colroom \@colroom\fullvsize% similar to LaTeX
\newdimen\@colht   \@colht\fullvsize

\newinsert\bx@A
\newinsert\bx@B
\newinsert\bx@C
\newinsert\bx@D
\newinsert\bx@E
\newinsert\bx@F
\newinsert\bx@G
\newinsert\bx@H
\newinsert\bx@I
\newinsert\bx@J
\newinsert\bx@K
\newinsert\bx@L
\newinsert\bx@M
\newinsert\bx@N
\newinsert\bx@O
\newinsert\bx@P

\newcount\@topnum% float parameters, adjust as you like
\newcount\maxtopnum \maxtopnum\thr@@
\newdimen\@toproom
\newdimen\maxtoproom \maxtoproom.4\fullvsize

\newcount\@botnum
\newcount\maxbotnum \maxbotnum\tw@
\newdimen\@botroom
\newdimen\maxbotroom \maxbotroom.3\fullvsize

\newcount\@dbltopnum
\newcount\maxdbltopnum \maxdbltopnum\tw@
\newdimen\@dbltoproom
\newdimen\maxdbltoproom \maxdbltoproom.4\fullvsize

\newcount\@botnum
\newcount\maxbotnum \maxbotnum\tw@
\newdimen\@botroom
\newdimen\maxbotroom \maxbotroom.3\fullvsize

\newskip\floatsep
\floatsep\baselineskip

\newif\if@insert
\newif\if@trybottom
\newif\if@topinsblocked
\newif\if@dbltopinsblocked

\def\@empty{}

\def\@freelist{\bx@A\bx@B\bx@C\bx@D\bx@E\bx@F\bx@G\bx@H\bx@I\bx@J
    \bx@K\bx@L\bx@M\bx@N\bx@O\bx@P}
\let\@currlist\@empty
\let\@toplist\@empty
\let\@botlist\@empty
\let\@dbltoplist\@empty
\let\@deferlist\@empty

\def\@addto#1#2{% #1: list, #2: box
    \xdef#1{#1#2}}

\def\@next#1#2{% #1: macro for the box, #2: list
    \xdef#1{\expandafter\@firstofmany#2!}%
    \xdef#2{\expandafter\@gobble#2}}

\newcount\@floatpenalty

\def\float#1{%
    \ifhmode
    \@bsphack
    \@floatpenalty-30000\relax
    \else
    \@floatpenalty-35000\relax
    \fi
    \@next\@currbox\@freelist
    \global\count\@currbox#1\relax
    \global\setbox\@currbox\vbox\bgroup
    \parindent\z@ \parskip\z@}

\def\endfloat{\par\vskip\z@\egroup
    \@addto\@currlist\@currbox
    \ifnum\@floatpenalty <-30000\relax
    \penalty -40000\relax
    \dimen@\prevdepth
    \vbox{}%
    \prevdepth\dimen@
    \penalty\@floatpenalty
    \else
    \vadjust{\penalty-40000\relax \vbox{}\penalty\@floatpenalty}%
    \@esphack
    \fi}

\def\dblfloat#1{%
    \ifhmode
    \@bsphack
    \@floatpenalty-30000\relax
    \else
    \@floatpenalty-35000\relax
    \fi
    \@next\@currbox\@freelist
    \global\count\@currbox-#1\relax
    \global\setbox\@currbox\vbox\bgroup
    \hsize\fullhsize
    \parindent\z@ \parskip\z@}

\def\enddblfloat{\par\vskip\z@\egroup
    \@addto\@currlist\@currbox
    \ifnum\@floatpenalty <-30000\relax
    \penalty -40000\relax
    \dimen@\prevdepth
    \vbox{}%
    \prevdepth\dimen@
    \penalty\@floatpenalty
    \else
    \vadjust{\penalty-40000\relax \vbox{}\penalty\@floatpenalty}%
    \@esphack
    \fi}

\def\@nextboxcnt{%
    \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter
    \count\expandafter\@firstofmany\@deferlist!}

\def\@nextboxht{%
    \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter
    \ht\expandafter\@firstofmany\@deferlist!}

\def\@firstofmany#1#2!{#1}

\def\fullline{\hbox to\fullhsize}
\def\makeheadline{\vbox to\z@{\vskip-22.5\p@
        \fullline{\vbox to8.5\p@{}\the\headline}\vss}\nointerlineskip}
\def\makefootline{\baselineskip24\p@\lineskiplimit\z@\fullline{\the\footline}}
\footline={\hss\tenrm\folio\hss}
\headline={\hss\tenrm\folio\hss}

\newif\if@twocolumn
\newif\if@threecolumn% not implemented yet
\newif\if@multicolumn
\newif\if@firstcolumn \@firstcolumntrue
\newif\if@secondcolumn \@secondcolumnfalse
\newbox\firstcolumn
\newbox\secondcolumn

\def\columnbox{\leftline{\pagebody}}% similat to the example from the TeX book
\newdimen\columnsep
\columnsep.5cm

\def\@outputonecol{\shipout\vbox{\makeheadline\pagebody\makefootline}%
    \advancepageno}

\def\onecolumn{\clearpage
    \global\hsize\fullhsize
    \global\@twocolumnfalse
    \global\@multicolumnfalse}

\def\twocolumn{\clearpage
    \global\hsize\fullhsize
    \global\advance\hsize-\columnsep
    \global\divide\hsize\tw@
    \global\@twocolumntrue \global\@firstcolumntrue
    \global\@multicolumntrue}

\def\@outputdblcol{\if@firstcolumn
    \global\setbox\firstcolumn=\columnbox
    \global\@firstcolumnfalse
    \else
    \doubleformat
    \advancepageno
    \global\@firstcolumntrue
    \global\@dbltopinsblockedfalse
    \global\@colht\fullvsize\fi}

\def\doubleformat{\shipout\vbox{%
        \makeheadline
        \ifx\@dbltoplist\@empty\else
        \loop
        \@next\@dbltopbox\@dbltoplist
        \@addto\@freelist\@dbltopbox
        \box\@dbltopbox
        \vskip\floatsep
        \unless\ifx\@dbltoplist\@empty\repeat
        \fi
        \fullline{\box\firstcolumn\hfil\columnbox}%
        \makefootline}}

\output{%
    \ifnum \outputpenalty<-\@M%B
    \@specialoutput
    \else%B
    \if@twocolumn%A
    \@outputdblcol
    \else
    \@outputonecol
    \fi%A
    \global\@topinsblockedfalse
    \global\@colroom\@colht
    \global\@topnum\z@
    \global\@toproom\z@
    \global\@botnum\z@
    \global\@botroom\z@
    %
    \if@multicolumn
    \ifx\@deferlist\@empty\else
    % dbl top floats
    \loop
    \@inserttrue
    \ifnum\@nextboxcnt>\m@ne \@insertfalse\fi
    \ifnum\@nextboxcnt<-2\relax \@insertfalse\fi
    \if@firstcolumn\else \@insertfalse\fi
    \ifnum\@dbltopnum<\maxdbltopnum \else \@insertfalse\fi
    \ifnum\@dbltopnum>\z@
        \ifdim\maxdbltoproom<\dimexpr\@dbltoproom+\@nextboxht+\floatsep\relax
    \@insertfalse\fi\fi
    \if@insert
    \@next\@nextbox\@deferlist
    \@addto\@dbltoplist\@nextbox
    \global\advance\@colht-\dimexpr\ht\@nextbox+\floatsep\relax
    \global\advance\@colroom-\dimexpr\ht\@nextbox+\floatsep\relax
    \global\advance\@dbltoproom\dimexpr\ht\@nextbox+\floatsep\relax
    \global\advance\@dbltopnum\@ne
    \fi
    \ifx\@deferlist\@empty \@insertfalse\fi
    \if@insert
    \repeat
    %
    \fi
    \fi
    %
    \ifx\@deferlist\@empty\else
    % Top floats
    \loop
    \@inserttrue
    \ifnum\@nextboxcnt<\z@ \@insertfalse\fi
    \ifnum\@nextboxcnt>\tw@ \@insertfalse\fi
    \ifnum\@topnum<\maxtopnum \else \@insertfalse\fi
    \ifnum\@topnum>\z@
        \ifdim\maxtoproom<\dimexpr\@toproom+\@nextboxht+\floatsep\relax
        \@insertfalse\fi\fi
    \if@insert
    \@next\@nextbox\@deferlist
    \@addto\@toplist\@nextbox
    \global\advance\@colroom-\dimexpr\ht\@nextbox+\floatsep\relax
    \global\advance\@toproom\dimexpr\ht\@nextbox+\floatsep\relax
    \global\advance\@topnum\@ne
    \fi
    \ifx\@deferlist\@empty \@insertfalse\fi
    \if@insert
    \repeat
    %
    \fi
    %
    \ifx\@deferlist\empty\else
    % Bottom floats:
    \loop
    \@inserttrue
    \ifnum\@nextboxcnt<\tw@ \@insertfalse\fi
    \ifdim\@nextboxht>\@colroom \@insertfalse\fi
    \ifnum\@botnum<\maxbotnum \else \@insertfalse\fi
    \ifnum\@botnum>\z@
        \ifdim\maxbotroom<\dimexpr\@botroom+\@nextboxht+\floatsep\relax
        \@insertfalse\fi\fi
    \if@insert
    \@next\@nextbox\@deferlist
    \@addto\@botlist\@nextbox
    \global\advance\@colroom-\dimexpr\ht\@nextbox+\floatsep\relax
    \global\advance\@botroom\dimexpr\ht\@nextbox+\floatsep\relax
    \global\advance\@botnum\@ne
    \fi
    \ifx\@deferlist\@empty \@insertfalse\fi
    \if@insert
    \repeat
    %
    \fi
    %
    \fi%B
    \ifnum\outputpenalty<-35000\relax
        \global\vsize\maxdimen\else\global\vsize\@colroom\fi}

\def\@specialoutput{%
    \ifnum\outputpenalty>-30000\relax%A
    \dosupereject
    \else%A
    \ifnum\outputpenalty<-35000\relax%B
    \ifnum\outputpenalty<-40000\relax \deadcycles\z@\fi
    \global\setbox\@ne\vbox{\unvbox\@cclv}%
    \else%B
    \setbox8\box\@cclv
    \dimen@\dimexpr\ht\@ne+\dp\@ne\relax
    \unvbox\@ne
    \ifvoid\footins\else\insert\footins{\unvbox\footins}\fi
    %
    \@inserttrue
    \ifx\@deferlist\@empty \else \@insertfalse\fi
    %
    \@next\@currbox\@currlist
    %
    \ifcase\count\@currbox%0
    \ifx\@deferlist\@empty \else \@insertfalse\fi
    \ifx\@botlist\@empty \else \@insertfalse\fi
    %\ifdim\ht\@currbox>\dimexpr\@colroom-5\baselineskip\relax         \@insertfalse\fi
    \ifdim\@colroom<\dimexpr\dimen@+\ht\@currbox+\tw@\floatsep+\thr@@%
        \baselineskip\relax \@insertfalse\fi
    \if@insert
    \vskip\floatsep
    \box\@currbox
    \vskip\floatsep
    \@addto\@freelist\@currbox
    \global\@topinsblockedtrue
    \global\@dbltopinsblockedtrue
    \else
    \count\@currbox\tw@
    \@addto\@deferlist\@currbox
    \fi
    \or%1
    \@inserttrue
    \ifx\@deferlist\@empty \else \@insertfalse\fi
    \ifx\@botlist\@empty \else \@insertfalse\fi
    \if@topinsblocked \@insertfalse\fi
    \ifnum\@topnum<\maxtopnum \else \@insertfalse\fi
    \ifnum\@topnum>\z@
    \ifdim\maxtoproom<\dimexpr\@toproom+\ht\@currbox+\floatsep\relax
        \@insertfalse\fi\fi
    \if@insert
    \@addto\@toplist\@currbox
    \global\advance\@colroom-\dimexpr\ht\@currbox+\floatsep\relax
    \global\advance\@toproom\dimexpr\ht\@currbox+\floatsep\relax
    \global\advance\@topnum\@ne
    \else
    \@addto\@deferlist\@currbox
    \fi
    %
    \or%2
    \@inserttrue
    \@trybottomfalse
    \ifx\@deferlist\@empty \else \@insertfalse\fi
    \ifx\@botlist\@empty \else \@insertfalse\fi
    \if@topinsblocked \@insertfalse\fi
    \ifnum\@topnum<\maxtopnum \else \@insertfalse\fi
    \ifnum\@topnum>\z@
    \ifdim\maxtoproom<\dimexpr\@toproom+\ht\@currbox+\floatsep\relax
    \@insertfalse\fi\fi
    \if@insert
    \@addto\@toplist\@currbox
    \global\advance\@colroom-\dimexpr\ht\@currbox+\floatsep\relax
    \global\advance\@toproom\dimexpr\ht\@currbox+\floatsep\relax
    \global\advance\@topnum\@ne
    \else
    \ifx\@deferlist\@empty \@trybottomtrue
    \else \@addto\@deferlist\@currbox\fi
    \fi
    %
    \if@trybottom
    \@inserttrue
    \ifdim\ht\@currbox>\dimexpr\@colroom-\floatsep\relax \@insertfalse\fi
    \ifnum\@botnum<\maxbotnum \else \@insertfalse\fi
    \ifnum\@botnum>\z@
    \ifdim\maxbotroom<\dimexpr\@botroom+\ht\@currbox+\floatsep\relax
        \@insertfalse\fi\fi
    \if@insert
    \@addto\@botlist\@currbox
    \global\advance\@colroom-\dimexpr\ht\@currbox+\floatsep\relax
    \global\advance\@botroom\dimexpr\ht\@currbox+\floatsep\relax
    \global\advance\@botnum\@ne
    \else
    \@addto\@deferlist\@currbox
    \fi
    %
    \fi
    %
    \or%3
    \@inserttrue
    \ifx\@deferlist\@empty \else \@insertfalse\fi
    \ifdim\ht\@currbox>\@colroom \@insertfalse\fi
    \ifnum\@botnum<\maxbotnum \else \@insertfalse\fi
    \ifnum\@botnum>\z@
        \ifdim\maxbotroom<\dimexpr\@botroom+\ht\@currbox+\floatsep\relax
        \@insertfalse\fi\fi
    \if@insert
    \@addto\@botlist\@currbox
    \global\advance\@colroom-\dimexpr\ht\@currbox+\floatsep\relax
    \global\advance\@botroom\dimexpr\ht\@currbox+\floatsep\relax
    \global\advance\@botnum\@ne
    \else
    \@addto\@deferlist\@currbox
    \fi
    %
    \fi
    %
    \ifnum\count\@currbox=\m@ne
    \@inserttrue
    \ifx\@deferlist\@empty \else \@insertfalse\fi
    \if@firstcolumn \else \@insertfalse\fi
    \ifx\@toplist\@empty \else \@insertfalse\fi
    \ifx\@botlist\@empty \else \@insertfalse\fi
    \ifx\@dblbotlist\@empty \else \@insertfalse\fi
    \if@dbltopinsblocked \@insertfalse\fi
    \ifnum\@dbltopnum<\maxdbltopnum \else \@insertfalse\fi
    \ifnum\@dbltopnum>\z@
        \ifdim\maxdbltoproom<\dimexpr\@dbltoproom+\ht\@currbox+\floatsep\relax
    \@insertfalse\fi\fi
    \if@insert
    \@addto\@dbltoplist\@currbox
    \global\advance\@colht-\dimexpr\ht\@currbox+\floatsep\relax
    \global\advance\@colroom-\dimexpr\ht\@currbox+\floatsep\relax
    \global\advance\@dbltoproom\dimexpr\ht\@currbox+\floatsep\relax
    \global\advance\@dbltopnum\@ne
    \else
    \@addto\@deferlist\@currbox
    \fi
    \fi
    %
    \fi%B
    \fi%A
}

\def\pagebody{\vbox to\@colht{\boxmaxdepth\maxdepth \pagecontents}}

\def\dosupereject{%
    \ifvoid\footins%A
    %
    \setbox8\vsplit\@cclv to\z@ \unvbox8\relax
    \setbox8\box\@cclv
    \xdef\@deferlist{\@toplist\@botlist\@deferlist}%
    \glet\@toplist\@empty \glet\@botlist\@empty
    \global\@colroom\fullvsize
    \global\@topinsblockedfalse
    \global\@colroom\@colht
    \global\@topnum\z@
    \global\@toproom\z@
    \global\@botnum\z@
    \global\@botroom\z@
    %
    \setbox\@cclv\vbox{}
    \ifx\@deferlist\empty%B
    \else%B
    \@inserttrue
    \loop   
    \ifdim\@nextboxht>\@colroom \@insertfalse\fi
    \if@insert
    \@next\@floatbox\@deferlist
    \@addto\@freelist\@floatbox
    \global\advance\@colroom-\dimexpr\ht\@floatbox+\floatsep\relax
    \global\setbox\@cclv\vbox{\unvbox\@cclv\box\@floatbox\vskip\floatsep}%
    \fi
    \ifx\@deferlist\@empty \@insertfalse\fi
    \if@insert
    \repeat
    %
    \setbox\@cclv\vbox to\colht{\unvbox\@cclv\vss}
    %
    \if@twocolumn
    \@outputdblcol
    \else
    \@outputonecol
    \fi
    \global\@topinsblockedfalse
    \global\@colroom\fullvsize
    \global\@topnum\z@
    \global\@toproom\z@
    \global\@botnum\z@
    \global\@botroom\z@
    %
    \fi%B
    %
    \ifx\@deferlist\@empty\else\supereject\fi
    \else%A
    \setbox\@cclv\vbox{\box\@cclv\vfil}
    \if@twocolumn
    \@outputdblcol
    \else
    \@outputonecol
    \fi
    \global\@topinsblockedfalse
    \global\@colroom\fullvsize
    \global\@topnum\z@
    \global\@toproom\z@
    \global\@botnum\z@
    \global\@botroom\z@
    \supereject
    \fi}

\def\pagecontents{\ifx\@toplist\@empty\else
    \loop
    \@next\@topbox\@toplist
    \@addto\@freelist\@topbox
    \box\@topbox
    \vskip\floatsep
    \unless\ifx\@toplist\@empty\repeat
    \fi
    \dimen@=\dp\@cclv \unvbox\@cclv % open up \box255
    \ifx\@botlist\@empty\else
    \loop
    \@next\@botbox\@botlist
    \@addto\@freelist\@botbox
    \vskip\floatsep
    \box\@botbox
    \unless\ifx\@botlist\@empty\repeat
    \fi
    \ifr@ggedbottom \kern-\dimen@ \vfil \fi
    \ifvoid\footins\else % footnote info is present
    \vskip\skip\footins
    \footnoterule
    \unvbox\footins\fi}

\def\eject{\vfill\par\break}
\def\supereject{\eject \write\m@ne{}\vbox{}\penalty -\@MM}

\def\clearpage{\supereject
    \if@twocolumn \if@firstcolumn\else \null\eject \fi\fi}

\outer\def\bye{%
    \supereject
    \if@twocolumn \if@firstcolumn\else \null\eject \fi\fi
    \end}

1. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.

\float0 ABCD0 \vskip20pt\endfloat% \float0 is like \midinsert

\float1 ABCD2 \vskip20pt\endfloat% \float1 like \topinsert

\float1 ABCD3 \vskip20pt\endfloat

\float1 ABCD4 \vskip20pt\endfloat

\float1 ABCD5 \vskip20pt\endfloat

\float1 ABCD6a \vskip20pt\endfloat

\float3 ABCD6b \vskip20pt\endfloat% \float3 is like \bottominsert (not defined in plain.tex)

\float3 ABCD6c \vskip20pt\endfloat

2. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua.

\float1 ABCD7 \vskip20pt\endfloat

\float1 ABCD8 \vskip20pt\endfloat

3. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
```

The order of floats is kept (unlike in plain.tex). You can switch between `\onecolumn`and `\twocolumn` as in LaTeX.

WARNING: Some things are not implemented yet:

- `\supereject` does not handle dblfloats.
- dblfloats in `\onecolumn` mode will lead to problems.
- More than 2 colums are not implemented yet (not difficult).

There are not many comments in the code. If you have questions please ask.

Comment: So may I ask that is it impossible to achieve without touching the output routines? And thank you for your help!

Comment: The output routine must be changed because it ships out the page.